# How to set default clouse param in View method?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried to set `else` default param in `ifLet` method but I face an error: `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. What did wrong?

```swift
extension View {
    func ifLet<Value, Then: View, Else: View>(
        _ value: Value?,
        then: (Value) -> Then,
        else: () -> View = { EmptyView() }
    ) -> _ConditionalContent<Then, Else> {
        if let value = value {
            return ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: then(value))
        } else {
            return ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: `else`())
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var test: String?

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            ifLet(test) { Text($0) }
            ifLet(test, then: { Text($0) }, else: { Text("Empty") })
        }
    }
}
```

The best solution without using the unofficial `_ConditionalContent` that might be changed or removed in the future check out [here](https://gist.github.com/darrarski/f3886d4d0a3598132a3fdd62b3061eb2#gistcomment-3177679)

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach. Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

```
struct TestingIfLet: View {
    var some: String?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ifLet(some, then: {value in Text("Test1 \(value)") })
            ifLet(some, then: {value in Text("Test2 \(value)") }, 
                else: { Text("Test3") })
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    func ifLet<Value, Then: View>(
        _ value: Value?,
        then: (Value) -> Then
    ) -> _ConditionalContent<Then, EmptyView> {
        if let value = value {
            return ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: then(value))
        } else {
            return ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: EmptyView())
        }
    }

    func ifLet<Value, Then: View, Else: View>(
        _ value: Value?,
        then: (Value) -> Then,
        else: () -> Else
    ) -> _ConditionalContent<Then, Else> {
        if let value = value {
            return ViewBuilder.buildEither(first: then(value))
        } else {
            return ViewBuilder.buildEither(second: `else`())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is about optional `else` param. How to write it?

Comment: @ViktorKushnerov It is not the way for generics with protocols... but you can try ))

Comment: when I use `\`else\`: (() -> Else)? = nil` the compiler asks me to put `else` param.